# Unable to get a keypress event on a non-event element working

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a modal component and want to set it up so when a user hits escape, the modal closes. However, I can't seem to get a keypress binding on the component working.

I started by trying a host binding:

```
@HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) public escapePressed(key) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

but I never see anything logged unless I'm in an input in my component. I changed the listener to `window:keypress` and I started seeing events logged, and thought maybe I can set it up to only fire if a modal is open, but I thought I should still try to figure out how to do it properly. Plus if multiple modals were created, there'd be multiple window bindings, all doing the same thing, which is inefficient.

I'm not sure how to address this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is focus. your component isn't focused. so workaround for this problem will be creating a div inside template and making it focus-able.

```
 <div id="rootdiv" tabindex="0" (keypress)="dosomething($event)" >
    <!-- other elements here --> 
 </div>
```

and 
within component

```
dosomething(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 27){
      //do something
   }
}
```

check this vanilla js example

```
        <script>
            function doit(e){
                console.log("called")
            }
        </script>
        <div id="container" tabindex="0" onkeypress="doit(e)">
            <input type="text" >
        </div>
        <style>
            *{
                margin:0;
            }
            #container{
                display: flex;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;   
            }

        </style>
        <script>
            var div = document.getElementById('container')
            div.focus()
        </script>
```

Comment: I had a feeling it had to do with focus, but I wasn't sure how to properly focus it. However, if focus shifts to an input for example, then it'd stop working again, right? Your response makes me wonder if the window bind + only triggering when a modal is open is the best way, but not sure how to avoid multiple binds.

Comment: as long as your input is within the div tag you are safe.

Comment: But with tabindex, wouldn't the user have to click the div first? I just tried it and I had to focus the div myself in order to get the keybinds to trigger. If the user has to click something, they can just click on the close box I have. Thanks for the info, but I don't think its the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Then import OnInit. and focus the div in function ngOnInit()

Comment: And if it doesn't work with OnInit, you can try AfterViewInit.

Comment: Reasonable ideas, unfortunately trying `.focus()` didn't do the trick :/

Comment: check that vanilla js example. you should query the div with ViewChild and then apply .. div.nativeElement.focus()